# Добавить в ul нужные данные с сервера!

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Li повторяет laravel, нужно чтобы по клику на категорию именно её подкатегории вставлялись в ul class="nav nav-list tree".
Я отслеживаю клик по категории с помощью $event, отправляю id этой категории, мне приходят подкатегории этой категории. Как их вставить в ul, именно в нажатую категорию? Так, чтобы это всё срабатывало само, даже если категории добавятся новые.

```
<li>
<div class="row">
<div class="hover">
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="">
        <div class="input-group">
        <a class="input-group-addon" href="#move"><i class="fa fa-arrows-v"></i></a>
        <a class="input-group-addon tree-toggle" href="" ng-click="showThis($event)"
           data-id="{{ $category['id'] }}"
           data-pivot-category_id="{{ $category['pivot']['category_id'] }}"
           data-pivot-categories_id="{{ $category['pivot']['categories_id'] }}"
        ><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></a>
        <input class="tree-control col-sm-2" type="text" name="path" value="{{ $category['path'] }}" />
        <input class="tree-control col-sm-6" type="text" name="title" value="{{ $category['title'] }}" />
        <input class="tree-control col-sm-4" type="text" name="name" value="{{ $category['name'] }}" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 text-right">
    <a class="input-group-addon" href="#edit" title="Редактировать"><small><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></small></a>
    <a class="input-group-addon" href="#add" title="Добавить новую"><small><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></small></a>
    <a class="input-group-addon" href="#save" title="Редактировать"><small><i class="fa fa-save"></i></small></a>
    <a class="input-group-addon" href="#cancel" title="Отменить / Удалить"><small><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></small></a>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<ul class="nav nav-list newTree" style="display: none" data-load="true">
</ul>
<ul class="nav nav-list tree" style="display: none" data-load="true">
<my-directive ng-repeat="cat in categories" category="cat">
            <li>@{{cat.name}}</li>
        </my-directive>
</ul>
</div>
</li>

$scope.showThis = function(event){
var catId = event.target.getAttribute('data-id');
if(catId == null){
catId = event.target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-id');
}
$http.get('api/cabinet/category/'+catId).then(callback);
function callback(data){
$scope.podCats = data.data;
}
};

.directive("myDirective", myDir);

function myDir() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: '',
        controller: 'cabinetCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        scope:{},
        bindToController: {
            category: "="
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: в директиве есть template
можешь контроллер прикрепить к ней
в директиву передаёшь данные, что нужны ей
через scope или bindToController
директива просто в себе сокроет реализацию этой li

помогите это сделать)

Comment: Ну может можно вставить директиву куда надо, подскажите.
На данный момент во все категории директива вставляет данные, а надо чтобы только в ту, которую нажали